# Incorrect behaviour of the authenticate controller in the Secure controller

Tags: java, security, playframework

I know there are already articles that covered this, but I'm having an 
issue that hasn't been resolved, even after reading those articles.

Here it goes:

I have 2 controllers, a MainController with this method:

```
public static void login(String username, String password) throws Throwable
{ 
    Secure.authenticate(username, password, false); 
}
```

And a SecurityController, an extension of Secure.Security with this 
method:

```
//overrides Security.authenticate(...)
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) { 
    return UserDAO.checkUserLogin(username, password); 
}
```

Then we have a view that pops out a small login screen (similar to 
that of twitter's login).
That view calls @{MainController.login()} with the input fields named correctly

When the user clicks the login button, the login controlller should be 
called, with this behaviour:
 - Correct? Refer to the url the user came from
 - Incorrect? Show standard login panel with error message

But that does not happen:

Play redirects to the login page in *any case*, and always without an error flash.
Simply the plain login screen, without any error messages.

(note that there should be indeed an error message, because the user 
does not exist in the db)

When I **do** create a user first, the application reacts the same way.

The url of the page login(...) redirects to is: http://localhost:9000/loginremember=false&password=secret&username=Bob

My question is now: 
Why does Play do this? 
Why doesn't it redirect to 
the page it came from (with redirectToOriginalUrl())? 
It shouldn't be giving those parameters to the login method of Secure, it should 
render at least the login screen with the error messages.

But even when I provide the details correctly, it still just redirects 
to the login view of the Secure module, with all the paramters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks beforehand, 
kind regards, 
Jasper

Comment: I fixed it. The people in the google group told me to use Secure.authenticate in the **view**, because otherwise, Play would GET-redirect to the login page. And therefore fail to call authenticate in Secure.Security.

But isn't there another way to call the authenticatecontroller in Secure? Without the redirect?

Thanks

Comment: You could create a SecurityService that's called from both places, that would be simple enough.

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira: Good point, but I guess the authenticatecontroller inherits from Controller as well. That would imply that it would also generate a redirect with GET. Therefore failing to authenticate.

But I guess I don't quite understand what you mean by SecurityService... :)

Appreciate the help though!

Comment: SecurityService as just a component/class that will handle all the business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser =)

Can you invoke a method in a class that doesn't implement Controller from a view? Otherwise I don't see how you could make that work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue with the implementation of a class that doesn't extend the `Controller` class. Works fine.

Thanks @Felipe Oliveira!

Comment: No problem Jasper! Let me know if I can help - you can always find me on my blog http://geeks.aretotally.in or http://playframework.info